# Shell: Find and replace word

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk, string-manipulation

I have a string in my shell script which is in a fixed format : `'[STATUS REPORT] PROJECT'`.
When user executes my shell script he will be asked to provide a value for `'PROJECT'`.

I would like to replace the word `'PROJECT'` with the user provide value. For Eg if `'ABCD'` was user input:

> '[STATUS REPORT] ABCD'

I have two issues:
1: How to tackle special characters like '&' in a project name? For eg:

```
echo "[STATUS REPORT] PROJECT" |  awk '{ gsub(/PROJECT/, "A&A"); print }'
```

and I get the following output:

> [STATUS REPORT] APROJECTA

2: My actual shell statement looks like this:

```
echo "[STATUS REPORT] PROJECT" |  awk '{ gsub(/PROJECT/, $ProjectName); print }'
```

where $ProjectName stores the project name provided by user. But this doesn't seem to work

How can I get this working properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will solve your 1st issue:

```
echo "[STATUS REPORT] PROJECT" |  awk '{ gsub(/PROJECT/, "A\\&A"); print }'
```

(`&` is a special char in awk substitution: it means "what has been matched".  You need to escape if with a `\`.  And as you are in a awk string, your need to put 2 `\` to produce one as `\` escape the next char as in `\n`.)

This will solve your 2nd issue:

```
ProjectName=toto
echo "[STATUS REPORT] PROJECT" |  awk -v "ProjectName=$ProjectName" '{ gsub(/PROJECT/, ProjectName); print }'
```

(**Edit**: notice the newly added `"` around `ProjectName=$ProjectName` so a space in `ProjectName` does not break the script.)

But awk is a big tool to perform string substitution, you might want to use sed:

```
echo "[STATUS REPORT] PROJECT" |  sed -e 's/PROJECT/A\&A/'
ProjectName=toto;
echo "[STATUS REPORT] PROJECT" |  sed -e "s/PROJECT/${ProjectName//\//\\/}/"
```

(**Edit**: a `/` in `ProjectName` will was breaking the initial solution.  I added the escaping of slashes, but some other char(s) still breaks it: `&`, `\1`, ...  I think plain bash shell bellow is safer.)

or in plain bash shell:

```
msg="[STATUS REPORT] PROJECT"
echo ${msg//PROJECT/A&A}
ProjectName=toto
echo ${msg//PROJECT/$ProjectName}
```

Comment: To be pedantic, this is not true: "`&` is a special char in regular expressions" -- `&` is special in the replacement string of the `sub` and `gsub` commands.

Comment: @glenn: true, I updated the answer.

Answer (score 3):

(Sorry, I don't have commenting privileges here)

From the snippet you've posted it's not very clear why you need to pipe the string to `awk`.

You can simply use the variable within the `echo` statement and bash will replace the variable:

```
echo "[STATUS REPORT] $ProjectName"
```

Comment: This shell script is part of a GUI App. The "[STATUS REPORT] PROJECT" line will be a user preference. A user can set this line to      "PROJECT [STATUS REPORT]" as his preference. I dont want to hard code this. Hence I'm looking to replace this programmatically

Comment: OK, I See. It looks like jfgagne's `awk` based solution may work better for you. Since `ProjectName` is declared as an `awk` variable, you shouldn't have any problems with special characters.